# Jquery and Ajax conflict, drag and drop not working

Tags: php, ajax, version-control, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a version control. So basically I always have two different questionnaires on the page, the most recent one and an old version.
The most recent questionnaire is displayed by a php-script on the page itself and for the old version I have a simple drop down menu and depending on the which option was selected I have a different questionnaire loaded below, using an AJAX script, so the questionnaire is still on the same initial page but in its own div. So I have like page in the page.

I'm using JQuery to drag and drop questions and change their order. Jquery works fine on the questionnaire which is loaded by the page itself, but doesn't work on the page fetched by the AJAX request. When I say it doesn't work, I mean it doesn't see the questions as drag-able.

And it is interesting that if I open the second page separately in the browser, it works fine. So it is something to do with a conflict between the ajax and jquery.

The script I'm using is:

```
<!-- Example JavaScript files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- Example jQuery code (JavaScript)  -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){



// Get items
    function getItems(exampleNr)
{
    var columns = [];

    $(exampleNr + ' ul.sortable-list').each(function(){
        columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(',,'));               
    });

    return columns.join('|');
}


// Example 2.1: Get items
$('#example-2-1 .sortable-list').sortable({
    connectWith: '#example-2-1 .sortable-list',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',

});
 //recent questionnaire button
$('#btn-get').click(function(){
var boo=getItems('#example-2-1');
    alert(boo);


});

// Example 3.1: Get items
$('#example-3-1 .sortable-list').sortable({
    connectWith: '#example-3-1 .sortable-list',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',

});

//old_version questionnaire button
$('#btn-get1').click(function(){
var boo=getItems('#example-3-1');
alert("Didi");

});

    });
    </script>
```

## I have the script on both of the pages, the main one and the one I fetch with the AJAX call. But even when I tried to have it just on one of them it still didnt see the second set of questions as draggable.

The AJAX Script I use is:

```
    <script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","display_old_versions.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }


    function myFunction()
    {document.write(divs);    
    location.href = "http://napred.cs.stir.ac.uk/php/drag1.php"+"?boxes="+divs+"&qText="+questions+"&token="+'<?php echo $table;?>';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create new objects, you need to add event handlers to them. Newly created DOM objects do not retain the handlers of the object they replace, unless you only edit their contents.

Based on what implementation you use for the drag&drop functionality, there are different solutions to this problem. jQuery UI's sortable for example utilize the "refresh" function.

In your case this should do the trick:

Add to the function getItems right before the return:

```
$(exampleNr + ' .sortable-list').sortable("refresh");
```

Comment: IamManish, this is what I thought was conflicting, but I still don't know how to sort it. Add the jQuery .on() to what? To the div with the old questionnaire on the second page?

Rene, sorry, yeah, I posted a code snippet just now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to DOM(Document Object Model)...

You are load a data through ajax because of this jquery will never about the new element that has been created (DOM Element)...

Try to add element using jQuery .on() function...

Comment: But the getItems(exampleNr) function doesn't add the new questions to the stack, it just creates an array to keep track of what is where. From what I understand I still have to add the elements with this  jQuery.on or .live, but Im not sure how.
I added the refresh bit you sent me, but still doesn't see them as draggable.